# create web2py apps dynamically

Tags: web-applications, web2py

Is there a way to create a web2py application through code instead of using the admin interface?

Not sure if app_create() in the admin module is what I am looking for.

`app_create(appname)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the admin app functionality can be accessed programmatically using the `gluon.admin` module. The `app_create` function in `gluon.admin` is used to create a new app. However, it takes a web2py `Request` object as the second argument in order to identify the web2py applications folder (where it will create the app) -- so the function must be called in an environment where a `Request` object exists (i.e., within a web2py application or shell), or you must pass in a mock `Request` object with the "folder" attribute set to the path of a web2py application (any web2py application path will do, even if it doesn't exist).

From an application or web2py shell (including a script run via the web2py shell):

```
from gluon.admin import app_create
app_create('myapp', request)
```

From an environment that does not include a `Request` object:

```
import os
from gluon.admin import app_create
from gluon.globals import Request
request = Request()
request.folder = os.path.join('path', 'to', 'web2py', 'applications', 'welcome')
app_create('myapp', request)
```